# Wamp not loading CSS or JS(?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on a website just for practice but when I try to open the index.html-file in Wamp(Directory:localhost:index.html) the browser does not seem to load anything but the HTML-file.

It looks exactly the same as when I'm in Atom loading it in the preview-window.

I have double checked the link to the CSS-file in the -tag in index.html. I cant seem to find anything wrong with it. What else could it depend on?

Since I dont own any domains i will post the code here, Ill try to minimize the space.

**[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/a4jdq2vm/)**

**HTML :**

```
<div class="menu">

  <!--Close icon for Menu-->
  <div class"icon-close">
  Close
  </div>
<!--Menu-->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="">123</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!--Main Body-->
<div class="container">

 <!--Icon Menu-->
  <div class="icon-menu">
  Menu
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
/*Initial Body*/
body {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
/*Basic Styling*/
.container {
  background-image: url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/
  codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/uber/bg.png');
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
/*Menu Elements Styling*/
.menu {
  background-color: #987;
  left: -285px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 285px;
}
.menu ul {
  border-top: 1px solid #636366;
  list-style: none;
  margin:  0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #636366;
  line-height: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left:  20px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}
.menu a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.icon-close {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.icon-menu {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
/*Not added "icon-menu i" properties*/
```

**JS :**

```
var main = function() {
  $('.icon-menu').click(function() {
    $('.menu').animate({
      left: "0px"
    }, 200);
    $('.body').animate({
      left: "285px"
    }, 200);
    });
    $('.icon-close').click(function() {
      $('.menu')animate({
        left: "-285px"
      }, 200);
      $('.body').animate({
        left: "0px"
      }, 200);
      });
};
```

Thanks!

/Simon

Comment: Any error in your logs? Also <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> should be <script src="http://

Comment: @Have you checked the developer console in your browser to see whether the files are loading? That's the most likely error. Perhaps your file paths are incorrect.

Comment: take a look at your browser network tab. (f12) and see what errors show

Comment: What do you meant by `Wamp(Directory:localhost:index.html)` does the URL in your browser start with `file:///`?

Comment: @Eric `src="//...` is fine it ensures the file is downloaded from google using the same protocol. It avoids the "some content is insecure" error in the browser

Comment: Is the background-image URL split across two lines in your CSS file?

Comment: Have you got structure like this: C:\wamp\www\index.html? Is WAMP running? Is CSS in C:\wamp\www\css\header.css?

Comment: @andrew, thanks didn't know

Comment: @Simonph what is your directory structure in wamp/www

Comment: @BhavinSolanki the directory for all the files is "wamp/www".

Comment: Ah now I see it @3y3skill3r! Thanks

Comment: @MikeSamuel thanks, now the background-image shows. Not it's just that the menu does not animate when ".icon-menu"-div is clicked.